# setting layout attribute for include

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android app I declare a custom view in a separate XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/download_interval_setter" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/Button_interval_up"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall">
</Button>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/Download_interval" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:numeric="integer">
</EditText>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Button_interval_down"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have my main.xml file where I would like to include the view declared in above XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/XMLStart" 
        android:textOn="@string/auto_update_on"
        android:textOff="@string/auto_update_off" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
<include layout="@layout/download_interval_setter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/XMLStart"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ShowRadars" 
        android:text="@string/show_radars" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/XMLStart"/>       
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ShowAccidents" 
        android:text="@string/show_accidents" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ShowRadars"
        android:layout_below="@id/XMLStart"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ShowConstraints" 
        android:text="@string/show_constraints" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/ShowRadars"/>     
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ShowPatrols" 
        android:text="@string/show_patrols" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/ShowRadars"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ShowConstraints"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I am trying to set the layout_toRightOf attribute of the included view but it is not set, as I can see also in hierarchyviewer

On the other hand if I simply copy-paste the content of the download_interval_setter.xml file to main.xml and declare the layout_toRightOf parameter there , the view will be positioned to right of as I want.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use `RelativeLayout` as root layout in the included xml file, because `android:layout_toRightOf` cannot be used with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: No it is not that. I tried it, works the same as with LinearLayout, besides that, as I mentioned, if I simply copy-paste the LinearLayout into the main.xml and add a android:layout_toRightOf attribute to the pasted LinearLayout, this will be positioned correctly. It is only with <include> that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the width and the height of the include layout